# Como fazer ul inline responsivo?

Tags: css, css3, layout-responsivo

Quero deixar esse código responsivo, porém sempre para de ser responsivo quando há duas linhas e 3 colunas.

```css
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: .25em;
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 16em;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a>Dados Pessoais</a></li>
    <li><a>Meus Objetivos</a></li>
    <li><a>Conhecimentos</a></li>
    <li><a>Formação Acadêmica</a></li>
    <li><a>Cursos Complementares</a></li>
    <li><a>Idiomas</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Aqui tá responsivo. O que vc queria exatamente?

Comment: Coloca essas propriedades em uma arquivo e use simulador de telas neles que ele buga é não fica responsivo

Comment: Foi isso que fiz. De acordo com o tamanho da tela, esses botões vão se alinhando automaticamente.

Comment: Mas vc mudou pela tela ou pelo simulador do navegador? Por que pela tela esta normal agora quando simula um celular não fica responsivo

Comment: Sim, pelo devtools com tela responsiva.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você já tentou isso dentro do `<head></head>`?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: markin funcionou, obrigado. Mas você pode explicar o que essas propriedades fazem?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp